# Can't open database from assets folder [Android]

Tags: android, sqlite

sorry for such a lame problem, but I can't solve it for 4 hours. I'm trying to copy database from /assets folder that i could use with SQLiteOpenHelper, but when i try to open InputStream it gives me error:

```
 E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

code:

```
public static final String DATABASE_PATH =  "/data/data/com.mycomp.myapp/databases/";
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db"; 

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        try {
            copyDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "blad" + e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void copyDatabase(Context context) throws IOException {
       String outfilename = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

       InputStream myinput = context.getAssets().open("database.db");

       OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(outfilename);

       byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
       int length;
       while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
          myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }

       myoutput.flush();
       myoutput.close();
       myinput.close();
    }
```

Comment: I *really* recommend that you use `SQLiteAssetHelper` rather than rolling your own code for this: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: can you post rest of 'copydDatabase' funtion?

Comment: sure. i just edited my post

Comment: Where are you trying to open the file from assests folder? It looks more like you're trying to open a sqlite db from a folder on external storage

Comment: I've created a .db file with SQlite browser, then i've imported into AndroidStudio. The program automatically created assets folder with the file, but after running program, the error occurs. Really have no idea what's wrong..

Comment: @AdamK Could you please write the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try this code and then please tell me result.
be sure you check all file names.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    //.......

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    dbHelper.createDatabase();

    dbHelper.openDatabase();
    // do stuff
    Cursor data =dbHelper.Sample_use_of_helper();
    dbHelper.close();
}


class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.mycomp.myapp/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "database.db";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;

        public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            this.myContext = context;
        }

        public void crateDatabase() throws IOException {
            boolean vtVarMi = isDatabaseExist();

            if (!vtVarMi) {
                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {
                    copyDataBase();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new Error("Error copying database");
                }
            }
        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }

        private boolean isDatabaseExist() {
            SQLiteDatabase kontrol = null;

            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                kontrol = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                kontrol = null;
            }

            if (kontrol != null) {
                kontrol.close();
            }
            return kontrol != null ? true : false;
        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

            // Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }

        public Cursor Sample_use_of_helper() {

            return myDataBase.query("TABLE_NAME", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {
            if (myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();
            super.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code works without any problems. Not sure what I missed, but I'll try to figure out and share.

Comment: @AdamK am just guessing . Maybe your code works only first time. After that system cant overwrite db file.

Comment: Finally figured it out. The problem was not with copyDatabase method, but with my misunderstanding of DatabaseHelper class role and no getReadableDatabase() method. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

remove **.db** extension from both **DB_NAME** and **.open("database.db")**
It looks ugly but currently same thing is working for me....
And before installing new apk please do ***Clear Data*** for earlier installed apk

And still if it won't work, please mention your database size.